# Tail Recursive Factorial Function in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I thought that the factorial function below is tail-recursive, when I tested it, works fine till 10 and becomes weird at 20 (negative output) and when I insert 100, the answer is 0:

```
def factorial(n: Int, m: Int = 1): Int = 
    if (n == 0) m else fact(n-1, m * n)
```

but when I put **@tailrec** above it, I get the following error:

```
error: not found: type tailrec
```

I can't understand why this function is not tail-recursive. A stack-recursive factorial function is:

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = 
    if (n == 0) 1 else n * factorial(n-1)
```

The above function modifies the external expression **after else** at each recursive call. Whereas the first function only modifies what's inside the function. Now, to make a recursive factorial function, what they do is create a function inside a function. But, can a recursive factorial function be created just with the body of the first function in this question?

Also, is the **"m"** in the former function a variable?

Edit: Now after doing what is suggested in the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292980/8237236),
I get the error message if a function is not tail-recursive:

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method factorial: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
```

Comment: tailrec won't change the result of the function, it will get negative or 0 because of integer overflow

Comment: What in the error message that tells you that the type `tailrec` wasn't found makes you think that the method is not tail-recursive?

Comment: @JörgWMittag A beginner coder here. AFAIK, tailrec checks if a function is tail-recursive and shows an error if it is not. I searched for what exact error is shown in such case, I could not find it. From the error I assumed that compiler couldn't determine the "type" of the function to be tailrec or couldn't classify it as one. 

There are many terminologies in programming of which I don't have in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several things:

- You have to import `@tailrec` annotation to be able to use it without a full name:

  ```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec
  def factorial(n: Int, m: Int = 1): Int = 
    if (n == 0) m else fact(n-1, m * n)
  ```

  Without `@tailrec` `scalac` will still be able to do tail recursion optimization, it just won't enforce it (it won't fail compilation if TRO won't be possible).
- Integer has a limited capacity - it's 32-bit [2-compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and everything bigger than 2^31-1 overflows and goes into negative numbers

So you have to import annotation or use a full name (`@scala.annotation.tailrec`) AND replace `Int` with something bigger (`Long` is also not enough, more like `BigInteger`).

Comment: "I can now safely assume that the function is tail-recursive after testing". You don't have to test to safely assume that. If you put a `@tailrec` annotation on the function and the compiler does not reject it, it is guaranteed to be tail-recursive. (That is the whole point of the annotation)